# Scipy: Maximize Distance between Interpolated Curves

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, mathematical-optimization

I have two interpolated curves created with `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` - how can I calculate the x value that maximizes the difference between these two curves?

Here is the relevant code:

```
from scipy import interpolate

units =   [0.0, 1.0, 2.0 ,..., 49.0, 50.0]
revenue = [0.0, 1.2, 2.4 ,..., 79.1, 80.0]
cost =    [0.3, 0.6, 0.9 ,..., 14.7, 15.0] 

revenue_func = interpolate.interp1d(units,revenue,kind='cubic')
cost_func = interpolate.interp1d(units,cost,kind='linear')
```

I need to find the value of units that maximizes `revenue_func - cost_func`.  This would be easy if I could limit the result to integer values for units, but I need to treat units as continuous between 0 and 50.

I'm stumped on this one, and would really appreciate any suggestions - even those that use another package besides scipy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On possibility is the **scipy.optimize** package, which includes both *minimize* and *minimize_scalar* functions. Since these functions search for a minimum instead of a maximum, you have to negate the function you want to maximize. To maximize revenue - cost

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

negated_profit_func = lambda x : cost_func(x) - revenue_func(x)
result = opt.minimize_scalar(negated_profit_func, bounds = (0, 50), method = 'bounded')

print(result)
```